# Start C array at 1

Tags: c, arrays

Is it possible, under some circumstance, in ANSI-C, to start arrays in index 1 instead of 0? (some compiler options which stays under the definition of ANSI-C, not MACROS or such)

e.g

```
int arr[2];
arr[2] = 5;
arr[1] = 4;
```

will be valid code which will behave properly.

Comment: No, and that's only good. Dialect formation is a bad thing for a language, as it splits the community and makes life worse for *everyone*.

Comment: Why do you want to do so and does this have any advantages? I don't see any.

Comment: in some mathematical application it's have to start from 1 indexing,
e.g nth prime would start from 1 not 0 , and maybe for efficiency reasons you would not write i-1 every time :p

Comment: @KerrekSB It's a question I was asked in homework. I was almost sure some compiler parameter would add "-1" to each array addressing.

Comment: @QuanticProgramming: That would just be so weird. It's like having a compiler parameter to double the result of every integer subtraction, or call every function twice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**.

There is no such thing in ANSI C.

Answer (score 3):

absolutely not, but what you can do is add an extra element if it simplifies your code.

like:

```
const int maxPrimes = 5;
int primes[maxPrimes+1] = {-1,2,3,5,7,11};
int thirdPrime = primes[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

A very ugly solution:

```
int arr[2];
arr = arr - sizeof(int);
arr[2] = 5;
arr[1] = 4;
```

Comment: Oops.  This code will not work.  Maybe `int *arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));`?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do, theoretically:

```
int  realArray[100];
int* startingAtOneArray = `;

startingAtOneArray[1] = 5;
```

This assignment is equal to:

```
*(startingAtOneArray + 1) = 5;
```

And since `startingAtOneArray` equals `startingAtOneArray` we get:

```
*(realArray - 1 + 1) = 5;
```

Which is:

```
realArray[0] = 5;
```

But it would be **stupid** to do so, because every programmer is deeply ingrained with the concept of array's indices starting at `0`.  So this will result in very weird bugs and confusion quickly.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it as a macro

```
#define ARRAYDECL(lo,hi) int arrlo = lo, arrhi = hi, arr[hi - lo + 1]
#define ARR(x) arr[x - arrlo]

ARRDECL(-2,10);
ARR(-1) = 20;   /* Takes arr[1] */
kk = ARR(4);    /* Takes arr[6] */
```

Another alternative is just to ignore the zeroth element and declare one more than what is required.